# Find a linear differential equation for a given function

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Is there any general method for finding a linear differential equation with polynomial coefficients that is satisfied by a given elementary function (or prove that no one exists)?

Example: 

If $f(x) = e^{\sqrt{x}}$, then
$$ 4xf''(x)+2f'(x)-f(x) = 0$$
Clearly, a first order linear differential equation with polynomial coefficients exists only for a given function $f(x)$ if $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} \in \mathbb{Q}(x)$, that is $f(x) = Ce^{\int{\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}}{dx}}$ for $p(x), q(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$.
Can you generalize this condition to arbitrary elementary functions with high order DEs?

Answer (score 2):

I know an example. When the order of the ODE is `two`, consider the given function is $f(x)=x^m+x^{m'}$ where $m$ and $m'$ are real roots for the equation $at^2+(b-a)t+c=0$ for some certain constants $a,b$ and $c$. In this case your second order equation would be $$ax^2y''+bxy'+cy=0$$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have the family of elementary solutions $y_1(x) = \cos{x}$ and $y_2(x) = \sin{x}$ and you are interested in finding what ODE these solutions satisfy. Then you can check that:

$$W(x) = \left| 
\begin{array}{ccc}
y_1 & y_2 & y(x) \\
y_1'& y_2'& y'(x)\\
y_1''&y_2''&y''(x)\\
\end{array}
\right| = 0 \tag{1}$$

yields to the ODE whose solutions are precisely $y_1$ and $y_2$:

$$y''+y = 0.$$ The equation $(1)$ tells us that $y_1$ and $y_2$ are linearly indepedent solutions of the equation $W(x;y,y_1,y_2)=0 $ ($W$ is called the *wronskian* or *Wronski determinant*).

Hope this sheds some light on your problem.

Cheers!